# Itext7 positioning exception

Tags: java, pdf, location, signature, itext7

For electronic signature, the original coordinates should be from the lower left corner to the upper right corner. But some pages will turn into the top left corner and the top right corner. What should I do

Comment: The coordinate system origin can be anywhere, inside or outside the visible area. This is controlled by the crop box of the page in question. Furthermore, the signature annotation **Rect** entry is a rectangle array, i.e. *an array of four numbers giving the coordinates of a pair of diagonally opposite corners*. It doesn't need to be the lower left / upper right, it may also be the upper left / lower right.

Comment: thx. how can I get the default location rule? even change it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "default location rule"?

Comment: For example, I use the following code.The origin coordinate is the lower left corner ```Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);appearance.setPageRect(rect);```

Answer (score 0):

You assume that for annotations, in particular signature form field widget annotations,

> the original coordinates should be from the lower left corner

and in a comment provide an example

> I use the following code. The origin coordinate is the lower left corner
>
> ```
> Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);
> appearance.setPageRect(rect);
> ```

Your assumption is wrong, the coordinate system origin can be *anywhere*, inside or outside the visible area. It indeed often is in the lower left of the visible page area but that merely happens because that often is the most simple variant to handle for the PDF generating software.

Actually the coordinates ranges of the visible page area are given by the **CropBox** entry of the respective page:

> **CropBox**
> rectangle
> *(Optional; inheritable)* A rectangle, expressed in default user space units, that shall define the visible region of default user space. When the page is displayed or printed, its contents shall be clipped (cropped) to this rectangle.

*(ISO 32000-1 Table 30 – Entries in a page object)*

Thus, if you have coordinates relative to the lower left of the visible area to position an annotation at, you have to add these relative coordinates to the coordinates of the lower left corner of the crop box.

Using iText 7, therefore, you position your `PdfSignatureAppearance appearance` on a `PdfPage page` relative to its lower left like this:

```
Rectangle crop = page.getCropBox();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(crop.getLeft() + 0, crop.getBottom() + 0, 200, 100);
appearance.setPageRect(rect);
```

(`getCropBox` already takes into account that **CropBox** is inheritable by inspecting ancestor nodes in the **Pages** tree, and also that it is optional by defaulting to the **MediaBox** of the page.)